# ASP.net UserControl Parameter Passing

Tags: asp.net, gridview, user-controls, drop-down-menu, parameter-passing

I am a newbie developer. I am creating a page + a user control. The aspx page contains a dropdownlist which is populated by a sql datasource that is on aspx page. The ascx page contains a gridview which is popluated by another sql datasource that is on ascx page.

The dropdownlist on aspx has a list of countries and the gridview (on ascx) should display data depending on the selected country.

My ascx page as follow.

```
    Partial Class UCtest
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Private priCountry As String

    Public Property PublicCountry() As String

    Get
        Return priCountry
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        priCountry = value
    End Set

    End Property

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("Country", priCountry)

    End Sub
    End Class

    <%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="UCtest.ascx.vb" Inherits="UCtest" %>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display.">
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" 
        SortExpression="CompanyName" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" 
        SortExpression="Country" />
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 

    SelectCommand="SELECT [CompanyName], [Country] FROM [Customers] WHERE ([Country] = ?)">
    <SelectParameters>

    </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My aspx page

```
    <%@ Register src="UCtest.ascx" tagname="UCtest" tagprefix="uc1" %>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Country" DataValueField="Country">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Country] FROM [Customers]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    <uc1:UCtest ID="UCtest1" runat="server" />

    Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged

    UCtest1.PublicCountry = DropDownList1.SelectedValue

    End Sub
```

It works fine if I just pass static values such as

```
    <uc1:UCtest ID="UCtest1" runat="server" PublicCountry="Mexico"/>
```

So I think I properly linked the User Control. But when I run the page, I only get blank page which mean ascx doesn't get data from aspx. what am I missing?

Comment: How/where are you populating the PublicCountry property from the ASPX?

Comment: This is what i tried to do here.
_Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
    UCtest1.PublicCountry = DropDownList1.SelectedValue
    End Sub_         

I know it's wrong but if i put .. 
_UCtest1.PublicCountry = "Mexico"_ in Page Load event it works fine. So how do i achieve dynamically with dropdownlist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a property called CountryId in your ascx control and when you select the country from dropdown that is CountryDropdown_SelectedIndexChanged() Event set your controls property something like this

```
    Private Sub New(Sender As [Object], e As EventArgs)
    YourControl.CountryId = Integer.Parse(CountryDropDown.SelectedVale)
    End Sub
```

And then  in your control's Property's set accessor bind your gridview by passing that id to your binding method
 something like

```
    Private _CountryId As Integer = 0
Public Property CountryId() As Integer
    Get
        Return _CountryId
    End Get
    Set
        _CountryId = value
        bindGridView(_CountryId)
    End Set
End Property
```

Hope this helps if not and have doubts or queries feel free to post your queries in comments. Happy Coding.

Comment: THanks Devjosh for your reply, ....... databindd(priCountry) 
Private Sub databindd(ByVal cccountry As String)
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("Country", cccountry)
End Sub ............ I am getting this error. No value given for one or more required parameters. what do i missing?

Comment: your bind method is receiving priCountry as an argument and you are adding a different value to your select Parameter SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("Country", cccountry) like this so check here please and also ensure that the name and number of parameters are same in you stored procedure/query.

@dany please do not forget to mark any post as answer/upvote if it worked for you it will help our other peers to go for the appropriate ones!thanks

Comment: well ya , i set the default value for the parameter and everything works fine now. Thanks for your help. :D

Comment: that was my pleasure. enjoy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

It could be that after you set the value (in SelectedIndexChanged) you need to force the user control to refresh itself, the SelectedIndexChanged event will probably be fired after your user control has prepared its data.

You could achieve this buy creating a public method on your user control and calling it after you set the value from he dropdown.

Comment: I tried to go it but ended up in getting those errors such as `No value given for one or more required parameters` a quick example would be very appriciated. Thanks.